# Control reaches end of non-void function in c++

Tags: c++, function

I wrote the following code to find a maximum of four numbers given by user:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    if(a>b){
        if(b>c){
            if(c>d){
                return a;
            }
            else if(a>d){
                return a;
            }
            else {
                return d;
            }
        }
        else if(a>c){
            return a;
        }
        else if (c>d) {
            return c;
        }
        else{
            return d;
        }
    }
 else if(b>c){
     if(c>d){
         return b;
     }
     else if(b>d){
         return b;
     }
     else{
         return b;
     }
 }
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    //scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cin>>c;
    cin>>d;
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    cout<< ans<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the following error:

> ```
> In function ‘int max_of_four(int, int, int, int)’:
> error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
> ```

Comment: **Hint:** what happens in your code if `a < b` but `b < c`?

Comment: Extra hint: [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Comment: @Darhuuk `std::max_element` would be even more useful.

Comment: @eerorika How so? That returns an iterator and there's no container to work with here. Note that `std::max` can take an `std::initializer_list` with >2 elements.

Comment: @Darhuuk Sure, but they could simplify their program and get rid of repetition by using an array.

Comment: At the end of the function, put `throw std::runtime_error("never supposed to get here");` and you're golden.

Comment: @Eljay Well, or you know... fix the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's flaw in your code actually. There will be many cases where there is value returned.

**HINT**: From a,b,c,d, first find greatest of a,b then find the greatest of c,d. Then compare the 2 answers. This is much easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 4):

The warning is reasonably clear:

> control reaches end of non-void function

Your function is non-`void`, so it expects a `return` -- but the compiler was able to determine that control reached the end of the function without finding a `return`. This means that there is some branch or some path that may be reached with valid inputs, where the code does not issue a `return`.

If you follow your code and imagine inputs where `a < b` and `b < c`, you will notice that the two top-level `if (a > b)` and `else if (b > c)` branches will fail -- resulting in you reaching the end of the function without ever returning.

To fix this warning, you will want to update your code so that all branches return correctly

Answer (score 0):

Continuing [@Human-Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608633/14597561), this is probably what you wish the `max_of_four` function to be:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            if(a>d)
                return a;            
            else
                return d;
        }
        else if(c>d)
            return c;
        else
            return d;
    }
    else if(b>c)
    {
        if(b>d)
            return b;
        else
            return d;
    }
    else if(c>d)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else
        return d;
}
```

You can also try following approaches:

First:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
 int max = 0;
 
 if(max <= a) max = a;
 if(max <= b) max = b;
 if(max <= c) max = c;
 if(max <= d) max = d;
 return max;   
}
```

Generalizing the method above:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int i;
    int arr[4]={a,b,c,d};
    int max=arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(max<arr[i])
            max=arr[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Second:

```
int max_of_two(int a, int b)
{ 
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{ 
    return max_of_two(max_of_two(a, b), max_of_two(c, d));
}
```

Third:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        if(a>c)
        {
            if(a>d)
            return a;
        }
    }
    
    if(b>c)
    {
        if(b>d)
        return b;
    }
    
    if(c>d)
    return c;
    
    else
    return d;
}
```

Fourth:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if(a>b && a>c && a>d)
    return a;
    
    else if(b>c && b>d)
    return b;
    
    else if(c>d)
    return c;
    
    else
    return d;
}
```

```
    :)
```